# Changing text colour with ColorPicker

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I'm having some issues getting the following code to work:

```
SideBarText.fontColour.addEventListener(ColorPickerEvent.CHANGE, changeTextColour);

function changeTextColour(e:ColorPickerEvent):void
{   
    trace (SideBarText.fontColour.selectedColor);
    trace (SideBarText.fontColour.hexValue);

    var colorInformation:ColorTransform = SideBarText.typeableText.transform.colorTransform;
    colorInformation.color = SideBarText.fontColour.selectedColor;
    SideBarText.typeableText.transform.colorTransform = colorInformation;
}
```

`fontColour` is the name of the ColorPicker, `SideBarText` is the variable name of the movieclip it is placed on and `SideBarText.typeableText` is the name of the text field inside the `SideBarText` movieclip that I am trying to change the color of. I get the following error:

```
TypeError: Error #1010: A term is undefined and has no properties.
    at App_fla::MainTimeline/changeTextColour()
    at flash.events::EventDispatcher/dispatchEventFunction()
    at flash.events::EventDispatcher/dispatchEvent()
    at fl.controls::ColorPicker/onSwatchClick()
```

Any help at all would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Some of your object is `null` or `undefined` in `changeTextColour()`. Suppose that it is `SideBarText.typeableText`. Check it in debuting progress. Set breakpoint and check if it defined or not.